# Handle specific byte from socket in Java

Tags: java

I'm using the code below to read a Unix socket:

```
    Boolean flag = false;
    while (!flag) {
        try {
            File socketFile = new File("./RISP");
            AFUNIXSocket sock = AFUNIXSocket.newInstance();
            sock.connect(new AFUNIXSocketAddress(socketFile));
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!CONNECTED!!!!!!!!!");
            flag = true;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("NOT CONNECTED....." + e);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException inter) {
            System.out.println(inter);
        }
    }
```

I need to read the first 4 bytes of each pack and convert them from binary to integer.

I've read many posts but I'm still looking for the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reader and Writer are designed for reading text.

For binary, you should try InputStream and OutputStream, in this case, you want DataInputStream, possibly buffered.

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

int len = in.readInt(); // read big-endian.
if (LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    len = Integer.reverseBytes(len);
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
in.readFully(bytes);
```

Comment: so in this case byte[] will contain the whole pack received ?

Comment: i tried the to use DataInputStream method but i got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception at line byte[] bytes = new byte[len];

Comment: @Daniele_r81 Using this code, you must write the length int (4) to the stream on the other side. Maybe you forgot this.

Comment: sorry @mad_manny i don't get it. probably i miss something but i never used this method so I'm afraid I'm missing something

Comment: @Daniele_r81 you need to make sure that a) the sender sends the 4 bytes as a length, and b) it sends it as big-endian.  If the length is sent as little endian, you need to reverse the bytes.

Comment: sorry but i was doing some test, actually the length of the packet is defined inside the first 4 byte, so i should convert as integer the first 4 byte. here look like i convert each single byte. how can i do that?

Comment: @Daniele_r81 this is what `readInt()` does. You need to check whether it is little endian or big endian. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

seems it works

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()));
                int len = -1;
                while ((len = in.readInt()) != -1) {
                    len = Integer.reverseBytes(len);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
                    in.readFully(bytes);
                    if (bytes.length > 4) {
                        System.out.println(" BYTE0: " + bytes[0] +
                                           " BYTE1: " + bytes[1] +
                                           " BYTE2: " + bytes[2] +
                                           " BYTE2: " + bytes[3] +
                                           " LENGHT: " + bytes.length);
                    }
                }
```

please let me know is i miss something.
thanks a lot to you guys.

Comment: as i said before, i got some problem, the first 4 byte converted to integer should give the size of the packet. but the result doesnt match with bytes.length. i need the size to get the next n=size byte of the message and keep doing this till the connection is close

Comment: This is what I stated in my answer, note `readInt()` and `readFully()` will throw an EOFException when you reach the end of the stream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey first of all thanks for your patience, i just don't understand one thing, when i print bytes.length it return the right size, but the size should be the same that i calculate from the first 4 byte. the first 4 byte i receive are BBB0:0, BBB1:0, BBB2:244, BBB3:1 so the packet looks like 244*256+1 bytes.

Comment: the same data using a python program it return as expected 49, 0, 0, 0 length 49.

Comment: which you do `readInt` you don't read those bytes again. When you do `readFully`, you read the bytes after those 4 bytes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry i don't get it....as i post before BYTE0..BYTE3 is already after those 4 byte? where did i read the firsts 4 byte? sorry if I'm asking you this but i really don't understand.

Comment: You read the first four bytes when you called `readInt` That is what I meant when I said "This is what readInt does"  From the Javadoc for this method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt-- "Returns:
the next four bytes of this input stream, interpreted as an int."